# Constructors and Methods on POCO classes with the IRepository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, poco, irepository

Is it okay to have a constructor or other non database accessing methods on POCO classes. For example when passing a view model to a controller.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(SomeViewModel model) 
{
    var entity = new SomePocoClasse(model);
    // ... then save entity to database

    return SomeActionResult
}
```

**Entity:**

```
public SomeClass() {}

public SomeClass(SomeViewModel model) 
{
    // create itself based on values in model
}

public void Update(SomeViewModel model)
{
    // Update itself base on values in model
}
```

The first entity constructor is for entity framework or regular creation

```
var entity = new entity 
{
    // set up properties
};
```

The second is for creation from SomeViewModel

```
var entity = new entity(SomeViewModel);
```

The method is for updating itself from SomeViewModel

```
var entity = SomeIRepository.Get(id);
entity.Update(SomeViewModel);
```

Or is the above bad practice which should go some where else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. In general, it's not necessarily bad practice to have a constructor on a POCO. There's any number of reasons why you might want or need that. However, you need to ensure that you maintain a parameterless constructor as well, or you'll cause issues with things like EF which won't know how to properly initialize your POCO class otherwise.

That said, what you're doing here is *not* good practice. You haven't provided a ton of code, but it appears that what you're doing is passing in the view model to the POCO constructor to set the properties on the POCO with those values. Rather, what you should be doing is pulling the entity fresh from the database and then mapping over any relevant properties on your view model to that entity instance. I supposed what you're doing could be fine solely when creating a new entity, but that means having two separate ways of populating your POCO class with values depending on whether you're creating or editing. That increases complexity and complexity means higher maintenance costs.

Instead, you should either use a library like AutoMapper or create a utility class to handle the mapping:

```
public static class SomePocoMapper
{
    public static SomePoco Map(SomeViewModel model)
    {
        return Map(model, null);
    }

    public static SomePoco Map(SomeViewModel model, SomePoco entity)
    {
        entity = entity ?? new SomePoco();
        // map over property values;
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Then in your create action:

```
var entity = SomePocoMapper.Map(model);
```

And in your edit action:

```
var entity = // get entity from database
SomePocoMapper.Map(model, entity);
```

Comment: I am only doing this when creating or Editing a class to be stored to the database. I assume this is still bad practice. And I do use a empty constructor as well. I am not a big fan or automapper so should I just have a method on the ViewModel that returns a new POCO entity. Or a separate service that does that

Comment: Again, you don't want to return a new entity, except in the scenario where you're creating the entity in the first place. When it comes to editing, you should make modifications to an instance pulled from the database. If you want to avoid AutoMapper, then go with something similar to the static mapping class I posted.

Comment: yes I understand that. What I am say is this. The constructor create the new entity. There is also a method called update which updates the entity based on the values in the view model. It all goes to one context. An update just makes changes to the context. Its my fault I didn't add more code but I added the update method above. I hope I'm explaining myself right.

Comment: It's still inappropriate. The entity shouldn't have knowledge of your view model and vice versa. In fact, a typical application may have multiple view models representing a single entity for different purposes, so then you'd have to start adding additional "update" methods and/or overloads. Simply, your view is bleeding into your domain, and that's bad.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.